# Eloquent not finding column if join in subquery

Tags: join, eloquent, subquery

When querying the database with the following query:

```php
Album::select('album.*')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($userId) {
        $query
            //->select('album.*') <- also tried this but didn't help
            ->join('accountuser_album', 'album.id', '=', 'accountuser_album.album_id')
            ->join('accountuser', 'accountuser_album.accountuser_id', '=', 'accountuser.id')
            ->where('accountuser.user_id', $userId);
    })
    ->where(function ($query) use ($userId) {
        //Otherqueries
    })
    ->paginate($this->pageLimit, ['*'], 'page', $this->pageNumber);
```

I get the following error:

```php
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accountuser.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `album` where (`accountuser`.`user_id` = 2))
```

Moving the join out of the subquery it works but that doesn't work for me because i need multiple subqueries with different joins

```php
Album::select('album.*')
    ->join('accountuser_album', 'album.id', '=', 'accountuser_album.album_id')
    ->join('accountuser', 'accountuser_album.accountuser_id', '=', 'accountuser.id')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($userId) {
        $query->where('accountuser.user_id', $userId);
    })
    ->where(function ($query) use ($userId) {
        //Otherqueries
    })
    ->paginate($this->pageLimit, ['*'], 'page', $this->pageNumber);
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: "I need multiple subqueries with different joins": What should the generated SQL look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't tell what the query eventually will look like. I understand SQL but I can't create it. So it's more or less trial and error. The question now is understanding why the above doesn't work so i can move on with the rest of the query.

Comment: Can you describe the query's goal in a sentence?

Comment: Album is connected to usergroups many to many which are connected to accountusers an album itself can also be connected many to many to accountusers and accountuser is connected to a user, I want to query al the albums on which the user has permissions. Permissions are defined by usergroups or directly to an accountuser in the accountuser table.

Comment: Take a look at `whereHas()`: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Thanks I will look in to that